# eliminating duplicates from vector of custom object - std:unique causes crash on free

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I have a vector of custom objects.

```
vector<MyObject*> newOnes;
```

After some operation of filling it, *newOnes* could have duplicate objects so I use std:unique().

```
std::unique(newOnes.begin(), newOnes.end(), isEquivalent); //isEquivalent return true if equal
```

Now after I am done using the vector, I go ahead and free memory using following function

```
void MyCalss::releaseSource(vector<MyObject*> v) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
        delete v[i];
}
```

On executing `releaseSource(newOnes);`
This results in crash. I know std:unique is creating dangling pointers hence the crash, but I can not use smart pointers here.

What can I do here to avoid this?

Will using std:unique like below solve the problem?

```
std::sort(new_combs.begin(), new_combs.end());
newOnes.erase(std::unique(newOnes.begin(), newOnes.end()), newOnes.end());
//// so operations
releaseSource(newOnes); //still need to free the other members
```

**I can not move to smart pointers now(unique/shared). That would involve changes to code I can not modify.**

Could I use std::set to remove duplicates here?

Comment: How is `isEquivalent` defined?

Comment: @AndyProwl yes isEquivalent() is defined and returns true if objects are same(compares strings)

Comment: Then objects may be *different* objects and still compare equal. Which leads to the problem I am outlining in my answer. I would advise you to consider using smart pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important advice first: **do not use raw pointers for performing manual memory management**. Consider using smart pointers instead (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, based on the particular ownership policy that fits your needs). That alone will wipe away the problem you are having.

Now considering your program:

> Will using std:unique like below solve the problem?

`std::unique()` does *not* remove duplicate elements from the container, it simply moves elements around and returns you an iterator to the new logical end of the container.

It is your responsibility then to actually remove the elements from the container, and you can do that the way you propose.

Notice, however, that if `isEquivalent` is defined in a way that returns `true` for objects that are *not* the same object (which sounds likely, otherwise you could have directly omitted the predicate), you may leak memory, because `std::unique` may overwrite the last pointer to a certain object.

So once again: **consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers and manual memory management**.

Comment: Can you explain this line of yours better please - "std::unique may overwrite the last pointer to a certain object" ?

Comment: Could I use std::set to remove duplicates here?

Comment: @AJ.: `std::set` is an option. If you have objects that compare equal but are not *physically* the same objects, and you store *owning* raw pointers in your `vector`, then `std::unique()` will overwrite the duplicate elements of your `vector` with subsequent elements. If those elements were the last pointers to some objects, you've lost the chance of doing `delete` on them, and you've leaked memory

Comment: set<MyObject*> s;
unsigned size = newOnes.size();
for( unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i ) s.insert( newOnes[i] );
newOnes.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );

Comment: @AJ.: That will remove duplicate pointers. Removing objects that compare equal according to `isEquivalent` also requires you to specify that predicate in `std::set`: `std::set<MyObject*, IsEquivalent> s(newOnes.begin(), newOnes.end());`

Answer (score 2):

unique don't delete you objects in vector.But the std::unique may copy some elements in vector
For example, if a vector of int has the follow element: [1 2 2 3 4].
Then the result of unique is: [1 2 3 4 4]. So, you can see, the element '4' was copy by unique.
Let's move this situation to pointer.If the '4' in vector is a pointer, then if you use `releaseSource` to delete the pointer, '4' will be deleted by twice. This is why the crash happen.